# remove() with variable as parameter

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove a file via filename using the remove function. The variable I am passing is an int and I need to add `.txt` to the end of it to construct the file name.

This is the code so far:

```
void delete_room(int room_number){
    char file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";
    remove(file_name);
}
```

However, when I try compile this I get the following:

```
main.cpp:347:10: error: no viable conversion from
      'std::__1::basic_string<char>' to 'char'
    char file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";
         ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/string:823:5: note:
      candidate function
    operator __self_view() const _NOEXCEPT { return __self_view(data(...
    ^
```

I believe this is because it's trying to convert the string to a char? (not too sure though!)

However, when I try explicitly type the filename e.g `remove('testing.txt')` it works.

I tried making a for loop to iterate through everything and append it to a variable `char filepath[]` however this wouldn't compile as it didn't let me declare the variable without immediately assigning a value to it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "*I believe this is because it's trying to convert the string to a char?*" Yes, exactly. You've answered your own question.

Comment: `char` is a **single** character, not a `std::string`.

Comment: @melpomene so how do I get around it? I gave an example of what I tried to do but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when i do something like ```remove('text.txt')``` it deletes the file

Comment: @wtreston No, it doesn't. That's also a type error. A `char` is a single character. Single quotes (`'X'`) create a `char`. You're probably trying to use a string. I'm not sure why you insist on putting `char` there.

Comment: @wtreston _"`remove('text.txt')`"_ Sure you didn't mean `remove("text.txt")` or are we talking about Delphi code?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry I meant it with double quotes ```remove("text.txt")``` when ran, successfully deletes the file. My understanding is "" is used for strings which is why the char error message is confusing me

Comment: @wtreston Well, as mentioned `char file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";` is wrong. You can't store a `std::string` result type into a single `char`. What you want is `std::string file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";`.

Comment: The char message is because `to_string()` returns a string object. There is no conversion (at least automatically) from a string to a char.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand now! Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me

Answer (score 0):

Try turning `file_name` into a string:

```
string file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";
```

or:

```
std::string file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";
```

**Edit:** After some good advice from Nathan Oliver, just try this instead:

```
remove((to_string(room_number) + ".txt").c_str());
```

or, if you really need it as a var (for reuse, or whatever) try this:

```
auto file_name =  to_string(room_number) + ".txt";
remove(filename.c_str())
```

The reason for this is that you are trying to convert a string to a char ([`to_string()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) returns a string). There is no such conversion, thus, the compiler throws an error. I'm 90% certain you actually mean a `string`, or a `char *` (but probably just a `string`).

Comment: Still get the same errror

Comment: Your updated answer is going to blow up in the OP's face.  You are taking a pointer to an object that will immediately go out of scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point. Got a better suggestion? Maybe a typecast?

Comment: Either `auto file_name = to_string(room_number) + ".txt"; remove(file_name.c_str())` or `remove((to_string(room_number) + ".txt").c_str());` will both work safely.

Comment: @wtreston I should also add that if you still need a char, you should probably explain why you need one and not a std::string in your question.

Comment: Might I suggest linking to a higher quality reference site? [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @Chipster I got mixed up. I posted the code I was testing with to see if I could get it working. I had it as a string originally. Changed it to a char because of the error message I got when attempting to compile.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You might suggest that. I might take your suggestion too! Fixed ;)

Comment: @wtreston Hmm. Okay. What was the message you got originally? Maybe that belongs in its own question though.